# How to parse following String present in HTML and build DOM Tree in Java?

Tags: java, html, dom

I have below string in html and I want to build Dom tree and get name value pair. How i can do this using html parser or xml parser or REGEXP. any code snippet will be useful. Thanks

```
<$$TagStarts>

<==0>Name0</==0><##0>Value0</##0>
<==1>Name1</==1><##1>Value1</##1>
<==2>Name2</==2><##2>Value2</##2>
<==3>Name3</==3><##3>Value3</##3>
<==4>Name4</==4><##4>Value4</##4>
<==5>Name5</==5><##5>Value5</##5>

</$$TagStarts>
```

Comment: Can you change the tag names? They are not valid HTML and you'll have a hard time building a DOM from them

Comment: Hi, i cannot change the tag names as i'm getting it from the service.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the tag names are just for sample.... and you will have some meaningful tag names...

Try using any of the following HTML parsers...

http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/

http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/

They will give you the W3 compliant document object.... After this it is just a game of `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementById` or Use XPath or Xquery to get the elements from the DOM.

Otherwise you can use the following... They have their own document object implementation...

http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/  [It also has some basic XPath support]

http://jsoup.org/  [It has jquery like `query` API]

**ADD** 
Check this...
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

I will recommend ... Either JSoup or Nekohtml